# Jquery ignore items with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to select all elements with the class 'tag', once them items have been selected i want to remove the items from that list that have the attribute 'data-tag-cat'.

```
var tags = $('.tag');
console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the attributes selector

```
$('.tag[data-tag-cat]').remove();
```

or if just mean remove from the collection, you can just not target them

```
var tags = $('.tag:not([data-tag-cat])');
```

or filter them out

```
var tags = $('.tag');

tags.not('[data-tag-cat]').stuff()
```

Comment: $('.tag:not([data-tag])'); this is what i ended up going with.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.each()` and `.attr('data-tag-cat')`

```
$('.tag').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-tag-cat').length)
    {
        $(this).remove();
    }
})
```